# Akka: actor spawning vs filling up mailboxes

Tags: scala, actor, akka

If you want to execute long running computations concurrently (on a single machine), Akka actors can help.

One approach is to spawn a new actor for each piece of work. Something like

```
while(true) {
    val actor = system.actorOf(Props[ProcessingActor])
    (actor ? msg).map { 
        ... 
        system.stop(actor)
    }
}
```

A second idea is to configure a set number of actors behind a router. And then send all messages to the router.

```
val router = system.actorOf(Props[ProcessingActor].withRouter(RoundRobinRouter(nrOfInstances = 5)))
while(true) {
    (router ? msg).map { ... }
}
```

I wonder, which is better if the system is overloaded (rate of incoming messages is higher than processing rate)?

Which will last longer? And will both eventually blow up the system with an OOMError?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Before you create a new `Actor` for each task you could also just use a `Future`. It really depends on what you want to achieve. To get as much work done with the least memory usage, you should use the actor/router approach. Futures are more expensive, because for each task would create a new instance of `Future` and `Promise`. But it really depends on your use case, which approach is the better. I just wouldn't create a lot of actors, when there really is no need for them. Especially as `system.actorOf` always creates a new error kernel.

Comment: Agreed - Futures are great for this type of use case.

Comment: @ericacm I disagree. If you know that you are going to do alot of work in the same manner and need some kind of error handling (e.g. restart failures). Then defining a set number of actors to handle the work seems much more reliable. The actors then receive the work they should do in a message, handle that, and send a response. If an actor crashes (for some reason) you have a supervisor that restarts it and tells it to try again. Using futures I believe this would be harder to do (certainly not impossible, but harder). But, I suppose it depends on the usecase.

Comment: Thx for clarifying. Makes sense that an actor is more expensive than a message.